# Random id generation on form save mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, forms, mongoose

So I currently have a form attached to a user id however when I fill out the form a random id gets generated therefore the form isn't actually getting attached to the user id so when the use goes back to their form the information isn't there because it saved to a new id and not the user.id.

Here is some code

```
// competition form details
router.get('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  CompetitionForm.findById(req.params.id, function(err, competition){
    res.render('dashboard/users/forms/competition-form.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Competition Form',
      competitions: competition
    });
  });
});

// competition form details post
router.post('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', (req, res) => {
  CompetitionForm.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {upsert:true}, (err, competition) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error saving data:  ${err}`);
      return res.send('Error saving data');
    }

    res.redirect('/dashboard');
    console.log(req.body);
  });
});

<form action="/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/{{user.id}}" method="post" class="competitionformsubmit">
```

The user id here is **5a7c7815656fa40fb5817630** however when I filled out the form, the id of **5a7c7c4ed8e033da6c40d260** got generated.

Not sure on what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong update method, instead of **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate)** which expects a query object as the first argument (you are giving it a string), you need the **[`findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate)** method which takes in a string id as first parameter.

`findByIdAndUpdate(id, ...)` is equivalent to `findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, ...)`

If using **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate)** to query on a different field other than the model's `_id` key, say on the `user` field, then you can restructure the code to reflect:

```
// competition form details post
router.post('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', (req, res) => {
  CompetitionForm.findOneAndUpdate(
    {user: req.params.id}, // <-- query object
    req.body, 
    {upsert:true}, 
    (err, competition) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error saving data:  ${err}`);
        return res.send('Error saving data');
      }

      res.redirect('/dashboard');
      console.log(req.body);
    });
});
```